# Is there a way to snmp shows real OID as 1.x.x, not as iso.x.x?

Tags: snmp

I actually do not install any mib to my ubuntu server, but snmp result is shown as 'iso.x.x', not 1.x.x. as below.

```
root@hanserver:~# snmpwalk -v2c -c private1 10.0.99.254 1.0.8802.1.1.2.1.1.6.1
iso.0.8802.1.1.2.1.1.6.1.2.1 = INTEGER: 4
iso.0.8802.1.1.2.1.1.6.1.2.1001 = INTEGER: 3
```

There is nothing in /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf, excpet " mibs : " and some notes.

Comment: Hello. You need to give more info. Start with what version of Ubuntu are you using? What prompted you to even look at this?

Comment: Ubuntu version is 20.04.3 LTS and snmpwalk version is 5.8. I'm just checking SNMP MIBs of our products.

Comment: Nevermind, I've found the solution. Add option -O n to show raw OID.